# Rendering react component in html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I just got comfortable with ReactJS within a few and want to actually start creating things with it. Before starting to really get into coding it, I made a basic test to see if React is doing what it is supposed to, and it's not. It's not rendering at all, and I don't see any Syntax errors in the code.
`<style>` in the index file is just for test of course, I'll use Sass later in external files of course.  What am I missing or doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Box = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
       return (
           
           <div>
               <h1>React</h1> 
               <h1>React2</h1>
           </div>
           
       );
   } 
});

ReactDOM.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="app.js"></script>
       
       <style>
           body {
               height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
               background-color: rebeccapurple;
           }
           
           #app {
               height: 100px;
               width: 100%;
               background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
           }
           
           * {
               margin: 0 auto;
               padding: 0;
           }
           
           h1, h2 {
               color: white;
           }
    
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      
       <div id="app"></div>
       
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it give any errors in your browsers console? if so please add the message.

Comment: Don't use require if you already include the file.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpeLjL Seems to work fine.

Comment: Your JavaScript may be executing before your document is being loaded and thus `document.getElementById('box')` may not be resolved.

Comment: I get this error in the Console: app.js:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

@AndrewLi Ty for letting me know

Comment: are you using webpack or wants to render this single file ?

Comment: @MayankShukla No, I am not using webpack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps it will work:

**1.** Remove these lines:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

**2.** include the `script` after the `div` where you defined the id, like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="app"></div>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**3.** Include the reference of `babel`, it required to `transpile` the `JSX` code into plain `js` code, include this reference in header:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

**4.** Define the type of the `script`, like this:

```
<script src="app.js" type='text/jsx'></script>
```

Check the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script type='text/jsx'>
         var Box = React.createClass({
             render: function () {
                 return (
                    <div>
                       <h1>React</h1> 
                       <h1>React2</h1>
                    </div>
                 );
             } 
         });

         ReactDOM.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('app'));
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did those the 1. and 2. already because of the kind suggestions above.. Added your 3rd and 4th step into my code and now it's working perfectly...
Thank you very much Mayank  :-)

Comment: glad, it helped you :)